# iOS UITableViewCell with textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got an `UITableViewCell` with an `UITextField` in it. This cell contains a max 3 digit string which I can edit. So far so good ;) Now I've made a previous and next button on a `UIToolbar` attached to the keyboard, which also displays correctly.

Now for the next implementation I do:

```
- (void) didPressNext:(Cell *)cell
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSInteger maxRows = [_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
    NSInteger maxSections = [_tableView numberOfSections];

    if (maxRows > (indexPath.row + 1)) { //In the same section
        NSIndexPath *next = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section];
        Cell * nextCell = (Cell *)[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:next];

        [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:next atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
        [nextCell becomeFirstResponder];

    } else if (maxSections > (indexPath.section + 1)) { //Is there a next section
        maxRows = [_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section + 1];
        if (maxRows != 0) { //If there are any
            NSIndexPath *next = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:indexPath.section + 1];

            Cell * nextCell = (Cell *)[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:next];
            if (nextCell.shirtNumber && !nextCell.shirtNumber.hidden) { //Contains a shirtNumber?
                [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:next atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];

                [nextCell becomeFirstResponder];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my cell I overwrite these methods:

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) isFirstResponder
{
    return [_shirtNumber isFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL) becomeFirstResponder
{
    return [_shirtNumber becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL) resignFirstResponder
{
    return [_shirtNumber resignFirstResponder];
}
```

And this process works correctly some of the times and sometimes when I press twice. The animation always works so I know I calculated the next indexPath correctly.

What am I doing wrong here?

The question is: "Why is it that sometimes the becomeFirstResponder doesn't work and returns no"

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is here- could you clarify? It it that you sometimes have to hit the button twice to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

in the end of the first if u got `[nextCell becomeFirstResponder];` 
which obviously cell cant be first responder.
and should be `[nextCell.shirtNumber  becomeFirstResponder];`

Comment: I extended cell to pass it to the textfield. Check the second piece of code which should clarify my point. The second time is a type which I will fix now